# Document with Scaled/Proportional Content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want every element in my document to resize proportionally based on screen size and screen resizing..

[please look at this Codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/VvRoWy).

[and here is the article of the codepen.](https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/)

In the Codepen you can see that the content is right at the center of the gray container and if you resize the gray container the content resizes **proportionally** and **still at the center** of the gray container right?

Now I want my whole document to behave like the gray container. the only difference is I want the content resize when the screen resizes not when user grab and resize the gray container. does it make sense?

So I created this container `scale-container` and I'll put every element inside it :

```js
const $el = $("#scale-container");
const elHeight = $el.outerHeight();
const elWidth = $el.outerWidth();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    doResize();
});


function doResize(event, ui) {
    let scale, origin;
    scale = Math.min(getViewPortWidth() / elWidth, getViewPortHeight() / elHeight);
    console.log(scale)
    $el.css({ transform: `translate(-50%, -50%) scale(${scale})` });

    function getViewPortWidth() {
        return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
    }

    function getViewPortHeight() {
        return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0)
    }
}

doResize();
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.scale-container {

/*fill whole screen if it's 1920*1080 */
  width: 1536px;
  height: 864px;


  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.bigred {
  color: red;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body>


  
      <div class="scale-container" id="scale-container">
      
        <h1>I am designed just so.</h1>
        <p>My design is intentional. I want to be scaled in such a way that scales the design. No reflows or anything, just straight up scaling. Kinda like SVG.</p>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/skull-and-crossbones.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="bigred"> ✖ ✖ ✖ </p>
        
      </div>

 
    


  <script SRC="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></script>
  <script SRC="script.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The issue is obvious, I want `scale-container` to fill the whole screen when it's possible (when the aspect ratio doesn't change) and I want it at the center of the screen ...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. in ./iframe.html, just use viewport units and you should be fine.

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
html {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
body {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
}
div#mainContainer {
    margin: calc((100vh - ((6/7) * 100vw)) / 2) 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc((6/7) * 100vw);
    background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    z-index: 1;
}
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 7/6) {
    div#mainContainer {
        margin: 0px calc((100vw - ((7/6) * 100vh)) / 2);
        width: calc((7/6) * 100vh);
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <iframe src="./iframe.html"></iframe>
</div>

</body></html>
```